# cordova android app memory leak issue in native part

Tags: android, cordova, memory-leaks, bluetooth

Hi our team is working on cordova android project in that im working native part,I mean  android part,Its basically a bluetooth project ,My problem is the app suddenly says "Unfortunatly app stoped".I know this is a memory leak.How can i know which part of my code is causing memory issue.Please can some one help me on this.

"I have tried canary leak it is not showing leaks"

**Update**

Can Anyone please tell me why "Unfortunately app stoped" error comes is it because of memory leak or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I've had such a problem a while ago and just needed to grant permission in the AndroidManifest.xml

Try to put this in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

If this does not fix it you can use [this plugin](https://github.com/Murthy582/Cordova-Plugin-Logcat) to generate a logcat. Maybe the logcat can help you identify the problem, if not just post the logcat here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I have used above permissions already  and i will check with logcat.